# Android Talkback focus whole view in scrollview

Tags: android, focus, talkback

I have a scrollView with a LinearLayout with a vertical orientation and 10 views inside it. When talkback is activated and the focus is going from one element down the other sometimes the focus is not showing the whole focused view (only the upper part is visible). ScrollVIew should scroll up/down to let the view be completely visible. So far I have not found the way to do it. Any idea would be welcome.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this for an Android app or a web app that you're testing with TalkBack? Do you have example code for us to look at to help answer your question?

Comment: Does it scroll once you get to the elements which are not visible at all to make them visible? Small amount of view not being in view might not really be a problem for the user. If they are using Talkback and can see the screen - they can still scroll manually to adjust it a little. If they are using Talkback and cannot see the screen at all - it doesn't matter if the view is not fully on the screen as long as Talkback is giving useful information.